# Unable to Return Queried Data From Firebase (Flutter/Dart)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Context: I'm trying to query and return a String (imgUrl) from Firebase. I'm always able to print the string inside the query, but the returned value is always null. I'm wondering if my query is wrong and am not sure what best practices are.

**Database Outline:**
[image]
**Query Function:**
This is the code under our DatabaseService() class, which contains all database queries and updating functions.

```dart
String getImageUrl(String _uid) {
    String _imgUrl;

    Firestore.instance
        .document('users/$_uid')
        .get()
        .then((value) => _imgUrl = value['imgUrl']);

    return _imgUrl;
  }
```

**Main:**
getImageUrl() is called under setImage(). The toast under setImage always returns null and so does the code under it.

```dart
String _uid;

// Sets variable '_uid' to the uid of the current user
// Gets called in initstate
Future _getUid() async {
     FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
     _uid = user.uid;
}

// Sets the profile photo. If there is no existing profile photo online,
// grab the image on the device. If there is no image online OR on the device,
// Display the default image
void setImage(String url) {
     // Get the url that's stored in the db
     String _tempUrl = DatabaseService().getImageUrl(_uid); // always ends up being null
     Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "_tempUrl: $_tempUrl");

     // Rest of the function
}

@override
void initState() {
     super.initState();
     _getUid();
}
```

Please let me know what to do to fix this as it's driving me crazy. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the method to the following:

```
 Future<String> getImageUrl(String _uid) async {
    String _imgUrl;

    DocumentSnapshot value =
        await Firestore.instance.document('users/$_uid').get();
    _imgUrl = value['imgUrl'];
    return _imgUrl;
  }
```

use async/await to wait for the future to finish, and then call it like the following:

```
  void setImage(String url) async{
     // Get the url that's stored in the db
     String _tempUrl = await DatabaseService().getImageUrl(_uid); // always ends up being null
     Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "_tempUrl: $_tempUrl");

     // Rest of the function
}
```